# Plone 4: restricting published content

Tags: workflow, plone

On a Plone 4.x install, can either

1. published content be restricted to a certain user/group or
2. private content be made to show in menus and searches for not-logged-in users ?

I have a customer who wants to be able to have content that can only be viewed by a certain user/group, but will show up in a menu or search when not logged in.

What would be the best approach for achieving this functionality?

Comment: Is the 'private' content linked in menus and searches? If so, what happens when anonymous users visit these links?

Comment: 'private' content only shows up to admins or the assigned users or groups. If an anonymous user visits a link it redirects to the login page as expected. My goal is to find a way to have content that shows up in menu and search, but redirects to login when the page or folder is visited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to customize your workflow as below:

- go to Zope Management Interface-> portal_workflow
- Create a new state, let's say "Trailer" (this is optional, you could customize an existing state instead...maybe the private state would be a good option for dealing with restrictions for specific users/groups)
- Remove all permissions but "Access contents information" from the Anonymous user in that specific state
- Push the "Update security settings" button

Done!
Now all contents in the "Trailer" state  will be searchable but not viewable by anonymous users.

Note: if you choose to create a new state, as I'd suggest, be sure to add all needed transitions too.

**Edit**:

Unfortunately I wasn't aware that in recent Plone's versions, there's a new index in the portal_catalog ([allowedRolesAndUsers](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/CatalogTool.py#L123)) that prevents the process above to work as it used to. The process above is still correct, though you'll need to override the default indexer.
First [create a new package with paster](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/paste.html#creating-an-add-on-product-skeleton) using the "plone" template. Then add in the main level of the package (e.g. my.package/my/package) a file called `indexers.py` with this:

```python
from zope.interface import Interface
from plone.indexer.decorator import indexer
from AccessControl.PermissionRole import rolesForPermissionOn
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
from Products.CMFCore.CatalogTool import _mergedLocalRoles

@indexer(Interface)
def allowedRolesAndUsers(obj):
    """Return a list of roles and users with View permission.

    Used by PortalCatalog to filter out items you're not allowed to see.
    """
    allowed = {}
    for r in rolesForPermissionOn('Access contents information', obj):
        allowed[r] = 1
    # shortcut roles and only index the most basic system role if the object
    # is viewable by either of those
    if 'Anonymous' in allowed:
        return ['Anonymous']
    elif 'Authenticated' in allowed:
        return ['Authenticated']
    localroles = {}
    try:
        acl_users = getToolByName(obj, 'acl_users', None)
        if acl_users is not None:
            localroles = acl_users._getAllLocalRoles(obj)
    except AttributeError:
        localroles = _mergedLocalRoles(obj)
    for user, roles in localroles.items():
        for role in roles:
            if role in allowed:
                allowed['user:' + user] = 1
    if 'Owner' in allowed:
        del allowed['Owner']
    return list(allowed.keys())
```

and then in the same level add a file `overrides.zcml` with this:

```xml
<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope">

    <adapter factory=".indexers.allowedRolesAndUsers" name="allowedRolesAndUsers" />

</configure>
```

In the end the tree of your product should look like this:

```
my.package/
├── my
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── package
│       ├── configure.zcml
│       ├── overrides.zcml
│       ├── indexers.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── profiles
│       │   └── default
│       │       └── metadata.xml
│       └── tests.py
├── README.txt
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

Last thing, you need to include the newly created egg in your buildout.cfg:

```
eggs =
        my.package

develop =
        src/my.package
```

Rerun buildout. That's all.

Comment: I am running Plone 4.1.2 and the 'Access contents information' seems to have no effect over an item displaying in the menu or search. Only when I check the 'View' permission does it show in the menu or search results. I have tried a custom state as well as modifying the private state and checking 'Access contents information' for anonymous users

Comment: Ignore this fact: you always need to keep 'Access contents information' in same configuration of "View", as Giacomo said.
Think them as a unique permission!

Comment: @keul it sounds like you are saying that View needs to be checked. If that is what you are saying, then that creates the same type of state as published, which does not accomplish the stated goal. It's entirely possible I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: you are probably modifying another workflow. I've just tried and it works, private contents show in menus and when you click on them you need to login.
@keul: In this specific case decoupling these two permission is the key.

Comment: @Giacoma I am trying to use the simple_publication_workflow. Is that what you used? Could you either describe or link to a screenshot of the permissions you have set on the private state? If I'm not missing a checkbox somewhere, some other plugin must be breaking things.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to double-check. I think this answer will help many other people.

Comment: This answer adresses only the item 2 of the question, or am I wrong?