# Accessing portal content with custom workflow and no 'View' permissions

Tags: python, plone, zodb

I have a problem where I need to be able to make custom content accessible for search and retrieval via portal_catalog by anonymous users but not viewable by them.

I used custom content types and a custom workflow, what I'm getting is most likely a permission issue. I defined a custom workflow through ZMI -> portal_workflow and then exported it into source code as an XML definition. I set the permissions for anonymous users as 'Access Content Information' but not 'View'. Note that 'active' in the code snippet is a workflow state that has that permission enabled -- [sales_workflow](https://gist.github.com/4599120)

Brain lookup works for 'Manager' role, but when the role is switched to 'Anonymous', catalog returns an empty list.

```
import unittest2 as unittest


from . import INTEGRATION_TESTING
from AccessControl import getSecurityManager

from plone.app.testing import setRoles, logout
from plone.app.testing import TEST_USER_ID

from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

def drop_to_anonymous(self):
    """
    Drop site roles to anonymous user only.
    Note this is a class method and not a function
    assign this method as a class member and then call it
    """
    logout()
    setRoles(self.portal, TEST_USER_ID, ['Anonymous'])
    user = getSecurityManager().getUser()
    roles =  user.getRolesInContext(self.portal)
    self.assertListEqual(['Anonymous'], roles)

class TestSalesRepWorkflow(unittest.TestCase):
    layer = INTEGRATION_TESTING
    drop_to_anonymous = drop_to_anonymous
    def setUp(self):
        self.portal = self.layer['portal']
        self.wftool = getToolByName(self.portal, 'portal_workflow')
        self.catalog = getToolByName(self.portal, 'portal_catalog')
    def test_workflow_lookup_anon(self):
        setRoles(self.portal, TEST_USER_ID, ['Manager'])
        self.portal.invokeFactory(
                                'CustomProduct',
                                'prod1',
                                title="Product 1"
                                )
        prod1 = self.portal['prod1']
        self.wftool.doActionFor(prod1, action='activate')
        review_state = self.wftool.getInfoFor(prod1, 'review_state')
        prod1.reindexObject()
        self.assertEqual('active', review_state)
        lookup = self.catalog(portal_type='CustomProduct', Title='Product 1',
                            review_state='active')
        #This test passes with managerial permissions
        self.assertEqual(len(lookup), 1)
        #Repeat the same test in 'Anonymous' role
        self.drop_to_anonymous()
        lookup1 = self.catalog(portal_type='CustomProduct', Title='Product 1',
                            review_state='active')
        #When dropped to anonymous role, the test fails, 
        #lookup returns an empty list
        self.assertEqual(len(lookup1), 1)
```

Is there a way to fix this without drastically reworking permissions?

Using unrestrictedSearchResults seems to fix the search, but whenever I attempt to run 'getObject' on a brain, the following error gets raised:

```
Unauthorized: You are not allowed to access 'XXX' in this context
```

Comment: That makes no sense at all; there is no code to vary catalog brain schema values based on access levels. Something else is wrong here (transaction commits perhaps)?

Comment: OK, I made a mistake, nothing is returned when I search anonymously.

Comment: So the anonymous user is not allowed to see the object even when in the `'active'` state. That sounds like a possible but normalish state; check your workflow, check that your workflow and permissions are set properly during the test, etc. Without the custom workflow, etc, there isn't anything here to help you further.

Comment: I attached custom workflow to the post. Basically I can either do both -- view an object and looking up from portal_catalog, or do neither. This post has a similar issue, but it's mostly involved with indexing -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667750/plone-4-restricting-published-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `active` state needs to give the View permission to Anonymous. Currently it is restricted to these roles:

```xml
<state state_id="active" title="">
 <!-- other information elided here --> 
 <permission-map name="View" acquired="False">
   <permission-role>Manager</permission-role>
   <permission-role>Owner</permission-role>
   <permission-role>Reviewer</permission-role>
   <permission-role>SalesRep</permission-role>
   <permission-role>Site Administrator</permission-role>
  </permission-map>
```

Without the View permission anonymous cannot see your objects even when given the `active` state, nor can they be found in the catalog by that user.

You can override this behaviour of the catalog by using the `.unrestrictedSearchResults()` method of the catalog:

```
lookup1 = self.catalog.unrestrictedSearchResults(
    portal_type='SalesProduct', Title='Product 1', review_state='active')
```

This method cannot be used from restricted code.

The returned brain objects are perfectly accessible by anonymous users, but you cannot use the `getObject()` method on them because that'll use the current user's permissions to traverse to it. If you need to get the actual object from the brain, there is again a special, private method to get to the actual object without those restrictions, called `._unrestrictedGetObject()`:

```
obj = brain._unrestrictedGetObject()
```

This method is, once again, only available to unrestricted code.

Comment: But if I give 'View' permission, anonymous user will be able to view the object from browser and I want to prevent that. I only want anonymous to be able to view an object from a specific view under specific circumstances.

Comment: @AlexVolkov: Updated the answer to add how to tell the catalog not to filter on the View permission.

Comment: I tried that, see my updated answer, I do get results from that query, but whenever I try to run getObject on a result, I get 'Unauthorized' error.

Comment: @AlexVolkov: You do keep expanding on the question, don't you. :-)

Comment: I'm guilty of that. I just want to make the thing work. I should have called it 'workflow permission issue' or something like that. Being specific doesn't help when the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexVolkov: you may want to edit the question now that you know what the problem is. :-) Just edit it to read as if you asked the right question to start with. That'll make it easier for others with similar problems to find it and get a useful answer.

Comment: Yay, test passes! I should probably tidy up the question.